# How to define a namespace using function and variable in php?

Tags: php, namespaces

This is actually a short question. Let's say I use namespaces in my php script. So I place this at the beginning of my file.

```
namespace Project\Module\Header_text_button\template;
```

Now what I want is to set this "Header_text_button" part dynamically, something like (completely demonstration):

```
namespace App\Modules\".$variable."\Controllers;
```

or

```
namespace Project\Module\.basename(basename(__DIR__)).\template;
```

How can I do such a thing, is this possible at all?

Comment: Thats not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as result it is NOT possible. It is executed at runtime before all the other stuff even was even created. besides it has to be defined at the very  top of the script so no other variables or dynamic stuff can't be created before.

[Php manual for namespace definition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php)